# Open TDecoratedMDIFrame Maximized

Tags: c++, windows, owlnext

I'm writing an application with Embarcadero RAD 2 Studio (borland) and the owlNext library.

There I create a `TDecoratedMDIFrame` Object, which I open by using

```
class TMDIApp : public owl::TApplication { // -------------------------------

    public:
    TMDIApp() : owl::TApplication(ProgName) {}

    TMDIApp(const char far* name, HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, const char far* cmdLine, int cmdShow) : owl::TApplication(name, instance, prevInstance, cmdLine, cmdShow) {}

    void InitMainWindow();
};

void TMDIApp::InitMainWindow() { // --------------------------
    PMAcMDI = new TMAcMDI;
    PMW = new TDecoratedMDIFrame(ProgName, MAC_MENU, *PMAcMDI);

    MainWindow = PMW;
}

int OwlMain(int, char* []) { // ------------------------
    return TMDIApp().Run();
}
```

So, in the end it get's opened by aplicat.cpp of the owlnext library using `MainWindow->ShowWindow(nCmdShow);`.

However, Now I want to open it maximized.

I made some research and came upon
`PMW->WindowProc(WM_SIZE,SIZE_MAXIMIZED,0);`
Which doesn't seem to do anything...

Does anyone of you know how to maximize this window or starting it maximized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found information about this problem at an old archive.org copy of the "OWL Programmer's Guide"
http://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_borlandborindowsforCVersion2.0ProgrammersGuideOct9_19152845/Borland_ObjectWindows_for_C_Version_2.0_Programmers_Guide_Oct93_djvu.txt

There it says:

> ~ ~ You can change how your application's main window is displayed by
>
> Specifying the mam setting the T Application data member nCmdShow,
>   which corresponds to the  ^ / WinMain parameter nCmdShow. You can set
>   this variable as soon as the Run
>
> function begins, up until the time you call T Application:
>   :lnitlnstance. This  effectively means you can set nCmdShow in either
>   the InitApplication or  InitMainWindow function.
>
> For example, suppose you want to display your window maximized 
>   whenever the user runs the application. You could set nCmdShow in your
>   InitMainWindow function:
>
> ## include   ttinclude
>
> class TMyApplication : public TApplication {  public :
>
> TMyApplication (char far *name) : TApplication (name) {}
>
> void InitMainWindow () ;
>
> 1; ■ ■
>
> void TMyApplication: : InitMainWindow () {
>
> SetMainWindow(new TFrameWindow ( , "Maximum Window") ) ;  nCmdShow =
>   SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;
>
> - }  int '
>
> OwlMain(int argc> char* argv[])  {
>
> , return TMyApplication("Wow!").Run();  } '
>
> nCmdShow can be set to any value appropriate as ( a parameter to the 
>   ShowWindow Windows function or the TWindow::Shozv member function, 
>   such as SW_HIDE, SW_SHOWNORMAL, SW_NORMAL, and so on.

So, in my case, adding `nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;` inside my `InitMainWindow ()` definition was enough.